# Como anexar imagens da camera ou da galeria em Swift

Tags: swift

Bom dia pessoal, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Swift, porém sou novo na linguagem e não sei algumas coisas, gostaria de saber como eu Anexo as imagens da minha galeria ou abro a camera do celular para tirar um foto.

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um código gigante na mão ou usar um pod, que é o que eu recomendo. Já usei o pod ALCameraViewController, que possibilita tanto tirar fotos quanto escolher da galeria. Você pode encontrar o github dele aqui:

https://github.com/AlexLittlejohn/ALCameraViewController

Passos para utilização:

1) Adicione no seu podfile:

```
pod 'ALCameraViewController'
```

2) Importe no seu arquivo que vai chamar a view controller da camerâ o pod, com a seguinte linha:

```
import ALCameraViewController
```

3) Na hora de chamar a view controller da câmera use o seguinte código:

```
let cameraViewController = CameraViewController { [weak self] image, asset in
    // A variável image que você recebe aqui vai ter a imagem que o usuário escolheu. Fique atento para o caso que ele cancela a escolha da imagem.
    self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

present(cameraViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Para mais dicas de swif, desenvolvimento iOS e empreendedorismo se inscreva no meu canal do youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCNghEgS-PkKMDbZfiwhvYpA

Answer (score 0):

Opa, blza!?
segue o código para fazer essa ação, nativo do ios, nao gasta adicionar lib nenhuma.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import APESuperHUD

class CadastroEleitorViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtNome: UITextField!
    var nome: String!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtSobrenome: UITextField!
    var sobrenome: String!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtEmail: UITextField!
    var email: String!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtSenha: UITextField!
    var senha: String!
    @IBOutlet weak var imagemPerfil: UIImageView!
    var imagem : UIImage!

    var mEleitorModel = EleitorModel()
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var userID : String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if FirebaseApp.app() == nil {
            FirebaseApp.configure()
        }

        ref = Database.database().reference()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        imagem = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        imagemPerfil.image = imagem
        imagemPerfil.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        imagemPerfil.layer.masksToBounds = false
        imagemPerfil.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        imagemPerfil.layer.cornerRadius = imagemPerfil.frame.size.width / 2
        imagemPerfil.clipsToBounds = true

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func botaoTirarFoto(_ sender: Any) {
        capturaFoto()
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle{
        return.lightContent // barra de status tema claro
    }

    @IBAction func iconeVoltar(_ sender: Any) {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func botaoCadastrar(_ sender: Any) {

        if validaCampos() {
            FunctionDefault.exibeProgress(mensagem: "Carregando...")
            criaUsuario()
        }
    }


    @IBAction func botaoCadastrarFacebook(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Usuario", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PagamentoViewController") as UIViewController
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    @IBAction func botaoLogin(_ sender: Any) {
        telaLogin()
    }

    func validaCampos() -> Bool {
        nome = txtNome.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        sobrenome = txtSobrenome.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        email = txtEmail.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        senha = txtSenha.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

        if nome.isEmpty {
            FunctionDefault.AlertMessage(title: "Alerta", message: "Por favor informe seu nome!", targetVC: self)
            return false
        }

        if sobrenome.isEmpty {
            FunctionDefault.AlertMessage(title: "Alerta", message: "Por favor informe seu sobrenome!", targetVC: self)
            return false
        }

        if email.isEmpty {
            FunctionDefault.AlertMessage(title: "Alerta", message: "Por favor informe seu e-mail!", targetVC: self)
            return false
        }

        if senha.isEmpty {
            FunctionDefault.AlertMessage(title: "Alerta", message: "Por favor informe uma senha!", targetVC: self)
            return false
        }

        if senha.count < 6 {
            FunctionDefault.AlertMessage(title: "Alerta", message: "Senha muito curta, digite no mínimo 6 caracteres!", targetVC: self)
            return false
        }

        if imagem == nil {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Foto do perfil", message: "Vamos adicionar uma foto ao seu perfil para que todos possam te identificar.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Selecionar foto", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
                self.capturaFoto()
            }))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return false
        }

        return true
    }

    func uploadImage() -> Void {
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let nomeImagem = self.nome + ".jpg"
        let storageRef = storage.reference().child("App/Eleitores").child(userID).child("ImagemPerfil").child(nomeImagem)
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

        if let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imagemPerfil.image!, 0.2){
            storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: metadata, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                if error == nil{
                    storageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
                        if error != nil {
                            // Handle any errors
                        } else {
                            self.mEleitorModel.urlFotoPerfil = url?.absoluteString
                            self.gravaUsuario()
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }

    func criaUsuario() -> Void {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: senha) { (user, error) in
            if error == nil {

                self.userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
                let date = Date()
                let formatter = DateFormatter()
                formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
                let dataAtual = formatter.string(from: date)

                self.mEleitorModel.id = self.userID
                self.mEleitorModel.nome = self.nome + " " + self.sobrenome
                self.mEleitorModel.email = self.email
                self.mEleitorModel.dataCadastro = dataAtual

                self.uploadImage()
            }
            else{
                if error.debugDescription.contains("The email address is already in use by another account."){
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Atenção", message: "Este email já consta em nosso cadastro, efetue o login ou relembre sua senha.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Relembrar Senha", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
                        self.telaAlterarSenha()
                    }))
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Login", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
                        self.telaLogin()
                    }))
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                }
                FunctionDefault.dismissProgrees()
                FunctionDefault.AlertMessage(title: "Erro", message: "Ocorreu uma falha ao processar seu pedido, revise seus dados e tente novamente!", targetVC: self)
            }
        }
    }

    func gravaUsuario() -> Void {

        let encodedObject = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self.mEleitorModel)
        let jsonObject = String(data: encodedObject!, encoding: .utf8)
        let dict = FunctionDefault.convertToDictionary(text: jsonObject!)

        self.ref.child("eleitores").child(userID).setValue(dict)
        FunctionDefault.dismissProgrees()
        //TODO: tratar proxima tela
    }

    func capturaFoto() -> Void {
        let controller = UIImagePickerController()
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func telaLogin() -> Void {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Usuario", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as UIViewController
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func telaAlterarSenha() -> Void {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Usuario", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AlterarSenhaViewController") as UIViewController
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```